# Why is a downvoting option available in the primary voting?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

I am just curious why a downvoting option is enabled in the primary voting phase? Is it also available in the core election? If so, then what are the reasons which enables the vote down option in elections? In the real world we should vote whomever we want, but criticizing, or defaming others marked as a bad habit. So this shouldn't be applied on vote down on Stack Overflow?

This is not a feature request or objection. I just want to know the
reasons and use cases behind it.

Comment: worth noting that displayed primary vote count is limited to non-negative [for the reasons explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135577/165773)

Comment: Downvoting someone is not "defaming" them.  Even saying it's criticizing them is a stretch.

Comment: I agree with @Servy on this - all downvoting says is that you don't think that they should be a moderator; calling that "defaming" them is a major exaggeration at best.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Defamation has a rather specific definition.  It would require, among other things, making a false claim, and there is no claim being made that could be false.

Comment: @Servy I agree.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Only ten people may advance through to the final phase of the election.  Voting allows us to select the ones that we want through the *most*.  Voting someone *down* sends a strong message that you don't believe them to be fit for moderator.  It's not a shot at them personally, but it is a shot at how the community sees them as fit to take on a very, very large responsibility.

Comment: I'm not completely sure that voting someone down necessarily sends a strong message, theoretically it can also use to "balance" some candidates over other candidates.

Comment: @AlonEitan:  Yes, I say that, but it honestly feels like a popularity contest at times...

Comment: Agree 100% on that :)

Comment: @Makoto as I am not complete satisfy with your point, but i didn't down vote as it's opinions difference so why same thing not applicable for election candidates. please don't take it personal :)

Comment: @AbdulHameed upvotes and downvotes in meta is agreement/disagreement without any effect on your rep.. It is not meant to be taken personally

Comment: If I only do an upvote on my favourite candidate then they get one vote. If I also downvote all the other candidates then my favourite gets the equivalent of two votes fom me.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Why is that a problem?

Comment: @Servy I did not intend to suggest that there was any problem, it was just an observation about how I understand the voting mechanism.

Comment: @AdrianHHH that exactly am thinking too. let say we have `A` and `B` both have 20 supporters each. now the 20 for A only upvote for `A`. and the 20 (for B) upvote the `B` and downvote the A too. so what?

Comment: @AbdulHameed I mean, some people *could* do that.  Again, why is that a problem, if a person wants to use their votes to do everything they can to support just one person?  Of course you need to remember that this isn't an election for one position; at this stage it's an election for 10 people (and will eventually become an election for two) so people can and will support multiple candidates. If some people choose to still do anything to support just one person, that's fine, but it's certainly not the only sensible behavior.  It would be if there was only one opening, but there isn't just one.

Comment: @AdrianHHH This is SO.  If you want to click more you get more say, to a limit.  ;)

Comment: @Servy let's say I am in the supporters of `A` in above case. then I just have to encouraged to downvote `B` without any reason. but it's looks like that I am the only men in room with that thinking, if is it then discussion is over.

Comment: @AbdulHameed I mean, if you think B wouldn't be a good moderator, sure.  If you think they would be a good moderator then you're *not* incentivised to do that; you'd be incentivised to upvote them.

Comment: @Servy ok you made the points clearly. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

> In the real world we should vote whomever we want, but criticizing, or defaming others marked as a bad habit. So this shouldn't be applied on vote down on Stack Overflow?

I don't think downvoting is "criticizing or defaming." Remember, this is Meta - upvotes and downvotes on proposals simply express agreement or disagreement. So, basically, "yes, I think this person should be a moderator" or "no, I don't think that this person should be a moderator." It's not personal - it's simply a judgment on their suitability to be a moderator on this site. (In fact, I'd probably vote myself down if I were proposed as a moderator because I only have 5k rep and moderators should be 10k or higher so they have experience with the 10k moderation tools).

Comment: it's not about meta I just gave example about meta in comment. my original question about election down votes only

Comment: @AbdulHameed Why should election voting be different than any other kind of Meta voting, though?